# What does the ending of Candace Against the Universe actually imply?

Tags: plot-explanation, ending, phineas-and-ferb

The new Phineas and Ferb movie, Candace Against the Universe, has an ending scene where:

> Perry's wrist communicator goes off at the end of the large group musical number, and everyone turns to look at him.

The movie ends abruptly at that point, leaving the potential consequences of that event ambiguous. Obviously, it's intended as a funny moment, but my question is **what happens afterward?**

> Would this be implying a repeat of Across the Second Dimension, where Agent P's cover is blown and everyone is hit by the Amnesia-inator again and loses their memory of the events of the entire movie?

Or,

> Do the characters never find out that Perry is Agent P at all?

The movie takes place sometime after Across the Second Dimension, but before Last Day of Summer. This is in the later seasons, so could there be any clues to the answer lying in the episodes? For example, Heinz and the kids interact in "Night of the Living Pharmacists", which might clue us in to what happened in Candace Against the Universe. Then again, everyone in Danville loses their memories of the day at the end of that episode too, so it's hard to say what characters remember what throughout the timeline.

Comment: Note that there is a "continuity" issue with the movie and Last Day of Summer: at the end of the movie she has made her peace with never busting them, while in LDoS she is so obsessed with it that she travels back in time. There's also a continuity issue in "Act Your Age", (which is a flash forward) where Perry visits the "Doofenshmirtz mmm Incorporated" building, which is destroyed in "The Phineas and Ferb Effect". Given that both series are pretty liberal with time travel, including intentionally unexplained weirdness (eg Bradley's Arm), I think it's doubtful there's a real answer to this.